# Non-Consumable IAP for an app with registered users

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We have an app that has users accounts, it is cross platform for iOS, Android and Win phone, We are starting to suggest Non-Consumable IAP on all platforms.

The idea is that when a user bought this product it will be available to him on any platform. for that we are attaching the purchase to it's account in our app. So when he is logged in our server will notify the app that the user did purchase the product (No matter on what platform) and unlock it for him.

**NOW FOR THE PROBLEM**

Lets say user **A** bought the product with his **AppStore account**, We attach the purchase to its "**OurApp-account**". Now user B is logging in to our app with his "**OurApp-account**" but the **AppStore account** is still User **A** account.

In this case Apple will give him the product for free because it will refer to user A **AppStore account**.

What we need is that user B will have to change the App store account and purchase the product again.

Any Idea how can we do this ?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118365/consumable-vs-non-consumable-in-ios